# C# Complex Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, controller

Im looking for advice, tutorials and general help on this issue.

I current have a simple login system where the user types a username/password verify it on the database then I use [Authorize] tag's to set what pages can be used when a user logged in/logged out.

But rather than host 5 different system for 5 different clients i wanted to merge them.

So the client could log in using Username, Password and then choose there company.

I would require the company detail to be available at every controller so i could say "Pull users for this company", "Pull invoices for this company".

Am i going about this the wrong way. I just think one system would be easier to support, maintain and develop against.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purposes I have AllowFor attribute. It looks like:

```
public class AllowFor : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private UserType userTypes = UserType.NotAuthenticated;

    public AllowFor(UserType userTypes)
    {
        this.userTypes = userTypes;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!(filterContext.Controller is ApplicationController))
            throw new Exception("AllowFor attribute is acceptable only for ApplicationController");

        var controller = (ApplicationController)filterContext.Controller;

        if (!userTypes.HasFlag(controller.CurrentUserType))
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "AccessRestricted"
            };
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

ApplicationController is just my class inherited from Contoller.

```
public abstract class Application : Controller
{
    public UserType CurrentUserType
    {
        get
        {
            return currentUser.UserType;
        }
    }

    // singleton for current user

    protected User __currentUser = null;
    protected User currentUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (__currentUser == null && HttpContext != null && HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // access to sql based on:
                // HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
                // HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
                // etc
            }
            return __currentUser;
        }
    }

    // singleton for EF context

    private MyAppContext __context = null;
    protected MyAppContext context
    {
        get
        {
            if (__context == null)
            {
                __context = new MyAppContext();
            }
            return __context;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need it actually, but I find it quite useful. Just inherit your controller from ApplicationContoller and you're able to retrieve context and other objects with singleton pattern.

The usage of attribute is very easy, just mark your action with attribute:

```
[Authorize, AllowFor(UserType.Company)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ...
}
```

You can make your AllowFor attribute more useful and apply it to classes (controllers, for instance) instead of actions:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class,
                AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AllowFor : ActionFilterAttribute { ... }
```

If you want to fetch the user from your database based on forms authentication, you can follow one of two ways:

- Fetch by email
- Fetch by provider user key

It's quite easy to fetch by email, but this approach has several disadvantages:

- You must ensure that your membership provider requires unique email address (must set `requiresUniqueEmail` property of your Membership provider in `Web.config` to `true`)

Example:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" applicationName="GeekJob" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="100" passwordAttemptWindow="1440" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

- You must keep in mind that `user@server.com` is not `User@server.com`. If you need to fetch the user from database by email, you must have additional column `LoweredEmail` in your table. Also, don't forget about table index on `LoweredEmail` column. Also, don't forget to mark it with `[StringLength(450)]` attribute (in case if you use MS SQL Server, because string columns can't exceed 450 unicode symbols if you apply index on them).
- What if the user decides to change his email? You'll need to modify membership and your entities table. Sounds like we're on the way to [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

So I recommend to link membership and existing tables on `ProviderUserKey` property (you will also need additional column and index).

Now you can fetch the user easily by doing:

```
if (HttpContext != null && HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return context.Users.Where(u => u.UserKey == (Guid)mu.ProviderUserKey).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: So my next question is, How would I know what company the user works for?

Would i need to use his email/user saved using form authention cookie and then pool from the database?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post, take a look.

Comment: How do you use your Application : Controller? Do i inherit all my controller e.g. Home : Application?